# How to hide the empty product-collateral tab in details page?

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs

I want to hide the  `product-collateral` tab present in product details page when no value is entered for that attribute. am stuck here.

The tab coding in `view.phtml` is this:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

In `catalog.xml` it is called like:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">  
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

The `description.phtml` is this:

```
<?php $_description = Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute(Mage::registry('current_product'), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please guide me how to hide the tab when no value is entered in description attribute field.I dont exactly know the jquery responsible for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition here. This will skip the tab from rendering

```
...

<dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
    <?php  
        //ADD YOUR CONDITION HERE
        if($alias=="description") continue; 
        // if(trim($html)=="") continue;
    ?>
        <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
        ...

    ...

...
```

You can compare name of any tab here `if($alias=="NAME_OF_TAB")`

Comment: when I included this code `<?php  
        //ADD YOUR CONDITION HERE
        if($alias=="description") continue; 
    ?>` it is hiding the tab even when there is value.

Comment: you want to hide tab, if whole description content OR HTML is empty, right ?

Comment: yes. When No value is entered in that attribute field it should be hidden.

Comment: use `if(trim($html)=="") continue;`

Comment: hey it is working only for description attribute. When other attribute value is empty it is still displaying.

Comment: debug `$html` variable, and do add conditions accordingly

Comment: I have done mapping for each value of an attribute with an image. So even when I didnt select any attribute value, a broken image is getting displayed. Do you have any idea of resolving this issue. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why this ans is accepted? Its not working at all.